# Create a list of Key Value pairs using Key = Enums Name and Value = Enums value using best technique

Tags: c#, enums

In C# 4.0 - 5.0 how do you create a list of key value pairs where the key is the enums name's value and the value is the enums name value.

Also in C# how do you create a list of key value pairs where the key is the enums name and the value is the attributes EnumName name.

I want to have two seperate list based on the enum's name in order to retrieve the value or the human readable name from the attribtue.

example:

```
public enum QATypes
{

    [EnumMember(Value = "Black Box")]
     BlackBox = 10,
    [EnumMember(Value = "Integration Tests")]
     IntegrationTests = 20,
    [EnumMember(Value = "Acceptance Testing")]
     AcceptanceTesting= 30,
...

     }
```

and the  first list would look like this for values:

```
{{ key:"BlackBox", value:10 }, { key:"IntegrationTests ", value:20 },{ key:"AcceptanceTesting", value:30 },...}
```

and the second list would look like this for enumsmember:

```
{{ key:"BlackBox", value:"Black Box"}, { key:"IntegrationTests ", value:"Integration Tests"},{ key:"AcceptanceTesting", value:"Acceptance Testing"},...}
```

Comment: Could you explain why exactly do you need it this way? And shouldn't in the second list the key be the enum value itself?

Comment: Because in my scenario the fields names in ui varaiables will always be known, but the values will not always be known.

Answer (score 4):

You may use Reflection. Try this (assuming that all the enum members have an `EnumMemberAttribute`):

```
var qatype = typeof(QATypes);
var names = qatype.GetEnumNames();
var values = qatype.GetEnumValues().Cast<int>().ToList();
var nameValues = names.Select(n =>
        qatype.GetMember(n)[0]
            .CustomAttributes.First()
            .NamedArguments[0].TypedValue
            .Value)
    .ToList();
var valuesList = names.Select((n, index) =>
        new { key = n, value = values[index] })
    .ToList();
var nameValuesList = names.Select((n, index) =>
        new { key = n, value = nameValues[index] })
    .ToList();
```

Further on, since your question seems to be JSON - related, if you want to serialize the lists in the JSON format, you may use [Json.NET](http://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/):

```
var valuesJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(valuesList);
Console.WriteLine(valuesJson);
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "key": "BlackBox",
        "value": 10
    },
    {
        "key": "IntegrationTests",
        "value": 20
    },
    {
        "key": "AcceptanceTesting",
        "value": 30
    }
]
```

And

```
var nameValuesJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(nameValuesList);
Console.WriteLine(nameValuesJson);
```

Which outputs:

```
[
    {
        "key": "BlackBox",
        "value": "Black Box"
    },
    {
        "key": "IntegrationTests",
        "value": "Integration Tests"
    },
    {
        "key": "AcceptanceTesting",
        "value": "Acceptance Testing"
    }
]
```

**Some remarks about the returned order and exception handling**

Relying on the order of the items returned by the `GetEnumValues` and `GetEnumNames` seems *not* to be a potential issue, as both these methods rely internally on the same method:

```
[SecuritySafeCritical]
private static void GetCachedValuesAndNames
    (RuntimeType enumType, 
    out ulong[] values, 
    out string[] names, 
    bool getValues, 
    bool getNames)
```

and ultimately on this method:

```
[SecurityCritical, SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
[DllImport("QCall", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern void GetEnumValuesAndNames
    (RuntimeTypeHandle enumType, 
    ObjectHandleOnStack values, 
    ObjectHandleOnStack names, 
    bool getValues, 
    bool getNames);
```

The code snippet I provided doesn't cover all exceptions, it relies on the sample data provided in the original question. For example, it doesn't check for the existence of the `EnumMemberAttribute` or it's `Value` property. But this can be easily changed with a little amount of effort.

Comment: You're relying on the order of items returned by `GetEnumValues` and `GetEnumNames`, is that documented somewhere? While that might work, and forever, the logic is not very sound. The problem is for `valuesList` only.

Answer (score 3):

`Enum.GetValues` is dangerous when you have enum members with same values but different names, like:

```
enum { A, B = A, C }
```

You should use `Enum.GetNames` and then get the corresponding values.

I have this *helper* class to deal with similar things:

```
public static class Enum<T> where T : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetValues()
    {
        return (T[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> GetNames()
    {
        return Enum.GetNames(typeof(T));
    }

    public static T Parse(string @enum)
    {
        return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), @enum);
    }

    public static S GetAttribute<S>(string @enum) where S : Attribute
    {
        return (S)typeof(T).GetMember(@enum)[0]
                           .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(S), false)
                           .SingleOrDefault();
    }
}
```

This is fully generic, so you need a bit more typing to call. Now I can do:

```
var first = Enum<QATypes>.GetNames().ToDictionary(x => x, x => (int)Enum<QATypes>.Parse(x));

var second = first.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => Enum<QATypes>.GetAttribute<EnumMemberAttribute>(x.Key).Value);
```

You can create your own extension method in a suitable namespace where you need not pass the enum attribute type argument, to ease calling.

---

Also you can make the helper class non-static which will help you with type-inference better and *thus make calling code shorter*. Should look like:

```
var helper = new Enum<QATypes>();

var first = helper.GetNames().ToDictionary(x => x, x => (int)helper.Parse(x));

var second = first.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => helper.GetAttribute<EnumMemberAttribute>(x.Key).Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

For the first question:

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string,int>>();

foreach(var e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(QATypes)))
{
    list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,int>(e.ToString(), (int)e));
}
```

for the second question:

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>();
foreach(var e in typeof(QATypes).GetFields())
{
    var attribute = e.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumMemberAttribute))
                             .FirstOrDefault() as EnumMemberAttribute;
    if(attribute != null)
    {
        list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,string>(e.Name, attribute.Value));
    }
}
```

Comment: `GetValues` is not very good for this thing imo, fails when you have `e { A, B = A , C }`, `e.ToString()` will give `A` for `B`.